# What do you call a thing that raises something (e.g. an event)?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

Let's say I want to describe event model in some software. Conceptually there are two sides: the one which raises an event and another which receives it.

While I do know the [difference](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/cw-raise-rise.htm) between *to raise* and *to rise*, I'm not sure whether I should say
"*rising* side" or "*raising* side".

Comment: If you want to use the word "raise", then the thing that does the raising is the "***raiser***" (if it raised *itself*, and only itself, it would be the *riser*; i.e. "rise" is intransitive, but "raise" is transitive, and +r suffix works the same either way). But if you're not married to "raise", you might consider the more common terms in event-based programming: "***event source***" and "*event sink*", or "***publisher**-subscriber*" in more structured contexts (i.e. where events are *directed*, and sources and sinks know about each other).

Comment: Triggerer/Triggering side comes to mind

Comment: If you know the difference between *to raise* and *to rise*, then you also know the difference between *rising side* and *raising side*. If you do not know the latter, then you also do not know the former.

Comment: @RegDwigнt probably poor phrasing, but I didn't want this to be a direct question, i.e. some answers can recommend a stylistically better alternative.

Comment: You raise an exception, you trigger an event.

Comment: You could call the exception-raiser a [snitch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snitch#Noun) (an [informer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/informer#Noun)) but those terms perhaps don't apply to event triggerers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @mplungjan and @MarvMills point out, `trigger` is the accepted term.

> **trigger** *verb*
>   something that causes something else to happen

<sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trigger)</sub>

jQuery, the leading javascript framework, [uses this nomenclature](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) probably for its brevity. Native javascript (i.e. EMCAScript standard) calls it [`dispatchEvent` (MDN documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

If you need to describe code that originates an event, you can just call it the *event trigger*, as trigger has a noun definition that is well understood and fits within the analogy. *Triggerer* is clumsy, but should be understood by native english speakers. You can also go with *dispatcher*, *origin* (or originator, origin point, originating code etc.) and variations on these.

If none of those tickle your fancy, you can always try a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/trigger).

---

[Programming Exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) are really just specialized events. Most programming languages use throw-catch for describing these events; while it's a valid metaphorical description of normal events, I would not use throw-catch language for anything that wasn't an exception or error handling. *Raising* is also commonly used for exceptions, so I would shy away from that term as well.

An even older type of event programming is [Interrupt driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt), which have variously been described as triggered, messaged or signaled. Edge-triggering is a specific term to hardware interrupts; the term you suggest *rising-side* puts me in mind of the physical signal (voltage), so I would not use that term either.

Comment: *Signal* is also a fairly common term to use, depending on the context.